# How can I connect to a docker container in github actions?

Tags: docker, go, github, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to setup a unit test workflow with github actions.

There is a docker container that the unit test must use.

In my workflow, I pull and run the docker image (in the background), then run a local go application that runs tests by interacting with it.

```
          docker pull xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-container
          docker run -d xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-container
          sleep 10 # make sure container setup finishes
          docker exec my-container apk add curl
          docker exec my-container curl http://localhost:1234 -I

          go test .
```

I'm able to `docker exec` into the container and check if it's running successfully, so I know the container is actually working.

The unit test works locally, however in github actions I receive an error from my go app when trying to connect to the docker container, regardless of host name:

`Post "http://127.0.0.1:1234": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1234: connect: connection refused`

`Post "http://localhost:1234": dial tcp [::1]:1234: connect: connection refused`

Even after running the container with a name and trying to connect I get an error:

`Post "http://my-container:1234": dial tcp: lookup my-container: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I believe the simpler solution is using github actions `services` to run the container, however I couldn't figure out how to pull from a private ECR.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my problem, even though I had `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile, I needed to run the container with the ports flag `docker run -p 1234:1234 ...` to access it from host.

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs:
  dump-database:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: ubuntu
    services:
      anonymizer:
        image: anonymizer:latest
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
     steps:
       - name: Dump database
         run: |
           curl anonymizer:5432/dump > dump.sql
           head -n 150 dump.sql
```